# How to change the layout of the table in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `df`. I want to transform this into wide format to have STATUS (CA, CO, unknown, MCI) as columns in this format as shown below (the number are not going to be the same, this is just an example). How do I do it in R?

[image]

```
df <- structure(list(STATUS = c("CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", 
"CA", "CA", "CO", "CO", "CO", "CO", "CO", "CO", "CO", "CO", "MCI", 
"MCI", "MCI", "MCI", "MCI", "MCI", "MCI", "MCI", "unknown", "unknown", 
"unknown", "unknown", "unknown", "unknown", "unknown", "unknown", 
"unknown", "unknown"), ETHNICITY = c("AA", "AA", "Asian", "Asian", 
"Hispanic", "Hispanic", "NHW", "NHW", "AA", "AA", "Asian", "Asian", 
"Hispanic", "Hispanic", "NHW", "NHW", "AA", "AA", "Asian", "Asian", 
"Hispanic", "Hispanic", "NHW", "NHW", "AA", "AA", "AA", "Asian", 
"Asian", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "NHW", "NHW", "NHW"), SEX = c("1", 
"2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", 
"1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "-9", "1", 
"2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "-9", "1", "2"), `<65` = c(27L, 33L, 
8L, 5L, 20L, 43L, 628L, 587L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
26L, 49L, 9L, 14L, 15L, 28L, 221L, 164L, 0L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 
6L, 13L, 0L, 61L, 65L), `<70` = c(47L, 70L, 13L, 12L, 38L, 71L, 
1166L, 1155L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 39L, 85L, 13L, 
23L, 26L, 50L, 364L, 269L, 0L, 13L, 21L, 1L, 5L, 8L, 15L, 0L, 
85L, 81L), `<75` = c(78L, 137L, 26L, 21L, 61L, 106L, 1847L, 1857L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 54L, 120L, 22L, 30L, 39L, 64L, 
493L, 370L, 0L, 24L, 42L, 1L, 6L, 11L, 22L, 0L, 115L, 105L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-34L))
```

Comment: You can have a look at pivot_wider from the tidyr-package

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure that this is the right answer, but I think first you have to gather the `AGE` into a single column and the spread the `STATUS`. This is a combination of `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider`.

```r
df <- structure(list(
  STATUS = c(
    "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA",
    "CA", "CA", "CO", "CO", "CO", "CO", "CO", "CO", "CO", "CO", "MCI",
    "MCI", "MCI", "MCI", "MCI", "MCI", "MCI", "MCI", "unknown", "unknown",
    "unknown", "unknown", "unknown", "unknown", "unknown", "unknown",
    "unknown", "unknown"
  ),
  ETHNICITY = c(
    "AA", "AA", "Asian", "Asian",
    "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "NHW", "NHW", "AA", "AA", "Asian", "Asian",
    "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "NHW", "NHW", "AA", "AA", "Asian", "Asian",
    "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "NHW", "NHW", "AA", "AA", "AA", "Asian",
    "Asian", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "NHW", "NHW", "NHW"
  ), SEX = c(
    "1",
    "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2",
    "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "-9", "1",
    "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "-9", "1", "2"
  ), `<65` = c(
    27L, 33L,
    8L, 5L, 20L, 43L, 628L, 587L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
    26L, 49L, 9L, 14L, 15L, 28L, 221L, 164L, 0L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 4L,
    6L, 13L, 0L, 61L, 65L
  ), `<70` = c(
    47L, 70L, 13L, 12L, 38L, 71L,
    1166L, 1155L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 39L, 85L, 13L,
    23L, 26L, 50L, 364L, 269L, 0L, 13L, 21L, 1L, 5L, 8L, 15L, 0L,
    85L, 81L
  ), `<75` = c(
    78L, 137L, 26L, 21L, 61L, 106L, 1847L, 1857L,
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 54L, 120L, 22L, 30L, 39L, 64L,
    493L, 370L, 0L, 24L, 42L, 1L, 6L, 11L, 22L, 0L, 115L, 105L
  )
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  NA,
  -34L
))

library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(`<65`,`<70`,`<75`), names_to = "AGE") %>% 
  pivot_wider(values_from = value, names_from = STATUS) 
#> # A tibble: 30 x 7
#>    ETHNICITY SEX   AGE      CA    CO   MCI unknown
#>    <chr>     <chr> <chr> <int> <int> <int>   <int>
#>  1 AA        1     <65      27     0    26       6
#>  2 AA        1     <70      47     0    39      13
#>  3 AA        1     <75      78     0    54      24
#>  4 AA        2     <65      33     0    49       7
#>  5 AA        2     <70      70     0    85      21
#>  6 AA        2     <75     137     0   120      42
#>  7 Asian     1     <65       8     0     9       1
#>  8 Asian     1     <70      13     0    13       1
#>  9 Asian     1     <75      26     0    22       1
#> 10 Asian     2     <65       5     0    14       4
#> # ... with 20 more rows
```